# Can anyone advise me on what this JavaScript code does?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm currently in the process of redesigning a navigational login header that allows users to log in and access a certain part of our server. Currently, the header was coded using just plain JS, HTML, etc; absolutely no CSS.  The previous designer had a swap image on hover effect using plain JS and HTML, whereas I used CSS.

Below is the JS used, from my understanding it looks as if everything is just used for the image hover swap.. can anyone confirm?

If it's more than that, what exactly is it?  Keep in mind this code is found on a server login access page, directly below this code would be the HTML.

Would appreciate any info, thanks!

```
var ifclicked = 0
function describe(text){
   window.status = text;

}
function clearstatus(){
   window.status = "";
}

function changediv(){
   parent.Bottom.location = 'Intro.asp'
   ifclicked = 1
   //parent.LeftBottom.document.frmChange.Change.value = "Yes";
   //parent.LeftBottom.document.frmChange.submit();
}
function proceed(){
   if (ifclicked == 1){
   //parent.LeftTop.location = 'TopIntro.asp'; 
   //parent.LeftBottom.location = 'Intro.asp'
   parent.Bottom.document.frmChange.Change.value = "Yes";
   parent.Bottom.document.frmChange.submit();
   ifclicked = 0;
   }
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
 var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
   var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
   if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
```

Comment: `MM_*()` tends to be dreamweaver boiler plate code.

Comment: This is an image loader for a dreamweaver template.

Comment: I figured the bottom four functions were part of a DW template, my main concern were the ones up above.  Are they part of the same template?

As for breaking them down I didn't think I had to, nor do I think this question is "too specific" as I was simply looking for directional advise on what this code most likely does as my experience with JS is very little.

I'm not asking for a play by play, just simply what it looks like this code was meant to do.  The rest I can figure out on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `parent.Bottom` is indicative that an iframe named "Bottom" exists within the page.

Based on that, you can assume that the method `changeDiv()` is setting this iframe's content to Intro.asp, and that `proceed()` is submitting a form called frmChange within that iframe.

I would also add that the `MM_ methods` are not directly related to the `changeDive()` and `proceed()` method since I don't see any calls to either set of methods. The `MM_ set` of methods definitely look like image preloaders and swappers, but doesn't quite make sense why they would exist in a "login" page.

Comment: Ahhhhh, it all makes sense now.  Thank you so much!  I really appreciate you taking the time to explain that to me.